# Error get while installing ardupilot on virtualbox ubuntu 14.04.3

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, virtualbox, git

I want to implement [ardupilot](http://dev.ardupilot.com/wiki/setting-up-sitl-on-linux/). I installed `ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-64 bit version` via VirtualBox on windows8.1 on D drive and username is jaydeep.

Still this all fine. Now as per above link the first thing is, Download ardupilot, so I open terminal in ubuntu and run (without "sudo apt-get install" its gives error and suggest to use this, so append this code before actual command )

```
sudo apt-get install git clone git://github.com/diydrones/ardupilot.git
```

> jaydeep@jaydeep-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install git clone
>   git://github.com/diydrones/ardupilot.git
>
> [sudo] password for jaydeep:
>
> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>   state information... Done E: Unable to locate package clone E: Unable
>   to locate package git E: Couldn't find any package by regex
>   'git://github.com/diydrones'
>
> jaydeep@jaydeep-VirtualBox:~$

I can not figure it out. So how to resolve the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the command that you have typed has a little typo. Here's the command to install git:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

And to clone the git repository, you have to type the command:

```
git clone git://github.com/diydrones/ardupilot.git
```

**EDIT**: If you want to combine the commands then, type:

```
sudo apt-get install git && git clone git://github.com/diydrones/ardupilot.git
```

Comment: that I already mention, that without sudo its gave error and suggested to add this.

Comment: in your question you combined the two commands and that produced the error.

Comment: please, See my edit!

Comment: @Ajay2707 - If it answered your question then, please accept it as an answer.

Comment: yes dear, I already know that things..